# How do I write to z-buffer in a transparent Unity 5 shader without a shadow caster?

Tags: unity

I've seen plenty of examples of "priming the depth" buffer with this pass:

```
Pass
{
    Tags{ "LightMode" = "Always" }
    ColorMask 0
}
```

But it does nothing in Unity 5. How do I write to the depth buffer (_CameraDepthTexture) in Unity 5 without using a shadowcasting pass?

Comment: Can you describe your desired effect, just to ensure we're on the right page?

Comment: A water shader with refraction. I want to write depth buffers AFTER the shader renders so that other effects, like fog, will have a depth buffer that matches the water surface.